# proving $\displaystyle\sum_{s,r=0,s\ne r}^{n}C_rC_s=\frac{1}{2}\left(2^{2n}-\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Using $\displaystyle(1+x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n C_rx^r$, find $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^n C_r$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^n C_r^2$. Hence prove sum of product of two coefficients taken from $C_0,C_1,C_2\cdots,C_n$ is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\left(2^{2n}-\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)$. i.e. $\displaystyle\sum_{s,r=0,s\ne r}^{n}C_rC_s$

Here's what I tried so far,

$$\sum_{r=0}^n C_r=2^n$$

using the fact that $(1+x)^{2n}$, I was able to derive,

$$\sum_{r=0}^n C_r^2=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

But How can I proceed? Any Hint would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just square $\sum C_r$ and note it's a sum of products of desired form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{s,r=0.s\ne r}^nC_rC_s=(\sum_{r=0}^nC_r)^2-\sum_{r=0}^nC_r^2=2^{2n}-\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$  To get the $\frac{1}{2}$ you need to change $s\ne r$ to $s\lt r$.

Comment: How did you do the simplification in the first line? Is it a common formula?

Comment: I'm asking this line $\sum_{s,r=0.s\ne r}^nC_rC_s=(\sum_{r=0}^nC_r)^2-\sum_{r=0}^nC_r^2$

Comment: $(\sum_{r=0}^nC_r)^2=\sum_{r=0}^nC_r\sum_{s=0}^nC_s=\sum_{r,s=0,r\ne s}^nC_rC_s+$$\sum_{r,s=0,r= s}^nC_rC_s$, where the last term is $\sum_{r=0}^nC_r^2$

Answer (score 3):

In general for any sequence of real numbers $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$, we have that $$2\sum_{1 \le i <j \le n} a_i a_j=\left(\sum_{1 \le i \le n} a_i\right)^2-\left(\sum_{1 \le i \le n} a_i^2\right)$$ and this property is used here.

Comment: Minor error: factor of $2$ is needed for $i\lt j$  Also you should have written $i\ne j$ since you subtracted $i=j$ on the right.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks!